# Highstock. prevent gaps adding new line series

Tags: highcharts, series

I want to draw a line on a ohlc chart, but i dont want the new series to introduce gaps.
The first series (ohlc) should still place the candles in an nica way with constant gaps between them regardles of open-close times (i think its only the "ordinal" value that does this, but unfortunatelly you cant specify it at series level, but only axis level).

```
xAxis: {
    ordinal: true
},
```

example:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/5r97owky/8/
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

The gaps are caused by `ordinal` option. You can create additional `xAxis` for `line` series:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function() {
                var xAxes = this.xAxis,
                    extremes = xAxes[0].getExtremes();

                xAxes[1].setExtremes(extremes.min, extremes.max, true, false);
            }
        }
    },
    xAxis: [{}, {
        visible: false
    }],

    ...

});
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1mbo2zp4/

**API:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal